# Do I really need a <form> tag since I can pass my model in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm test driving Angular for the first time...building a form and I'm noticing I can pass my `UserModel` from the view to the component (controller) just fine without a `<form>` tag.

I've seen examples of the use of both but I'm wondering why I would use one when it seems like I don't need it. I could easily be making a ton of wrong assumptions here so please correct me.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <h1 class="mat-h1">Account</h1>
  <div class="form-container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="model.lastName">
    </mat-form-field>    
  </div>
  <button mat-button type="submit" (click)="submitForm(model)" color="primary">Save Settings</button>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from '../models/usermodel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})

export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

model = new UserModel();

constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

ngOnInit() {}

submitForm(userModel: UserModel) {
  console.log(userModel);
}
}
```

p.s. I tried getting this to work in StackBlitz but kept getting a ton of errors related to material references missing. Not sure what else I'm missing for that to work either. [Here it is anyway](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ebfbo).

Comment: You might get away with this approach in some cases but for a more complex form applications where you need to enable / disable different parts of the screen based on the validity of the form you will need the form. To give an example, imagine a contact form that needs a subject and a message etc and you don't want the user to be able to send the request without filling the fields you better have the form on place and disable/enable the send button based on form validity. So you put let's say `required` in input tags and check `form.valid` to show general condition of form validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you used is probably not going to give you any headaches, as it does often work for simple forms.

Nevertheless, there is a special way Angular can handle forms. Angular Forms give you a lot of nice features, e.g. form validation, special CSS classes for these validations, sharing information across HTML elements, etc. And as far as I know an Angular Form has to be wrapped in a < form > element.

There are two possible approachs, Template Driven and Reactive. The official documentation can be found at:

- https://angular.io/guide/forms
- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your app.component.ts, below name is define

```
    model = {
    firstName:null,
    lastName:null
  }submitForm(model){
    console.log(model)
  }
```